# Postgres seldom deadlock diaglostics

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, deadlock

In Postgres running on AWS RDS sometimes (once per 3 month) deadlock happens. Symptoms: application stop normally work, DBLoadCPU increased few times comparing to normal. Application reboot doesn't help, DB reboot solve problem.
In app log at the time when DBLoadCPU begin to increase I see batch update which usually takes few seconds but in this case newer finished. This batch update very simple - transaction with a loop from application few thousand times:

```
UPDATE BigTable
SET ColA = value 
WHERE PK = some-key;
```

After that `UPDATE table_a ...`
Only another update on BigTable I see is procedure, called every 3 seconds with different conditions:

```
PROCEDURE proc1
...
BEGIN
    LOCK TABLE table_a IN EXCLUSIVE MODE;
    ...
    LOOP -- about 10 times
        ...
        UPDATE BigTable
        SET ColB = some-value
        WHERE some-condition;
        ...
        UPDATE BigTable
        SET ColC = ColC + 1
        WHERE some-condition;

        UPDATE table_a ...
   END LOOP;
```

By application logic batch update should newer update same rows as proc1 in the same time. I see no reason for deadlock here. DB log not anymore available.

How to diagnose such a problem? If it happens again will be not much time - need reboot DB soon.

Could you recommend good article or video?

Comment: That is definitely *not* a deadlock. Deadlocks get resolved in the database, and locked processes don't consume CPU. When the problem happens, take some snapshots of `pg_stat_activity`. It is likely that this is an application problem.

Comment: Thank you @LaurenzAlbe, I updated description and mention exclusive lock. I still suspect deadlock because problem exists until DB reboot. May be lock IN EXCLUSIVE MODE must be replaced to ROW EXCLUSIVE? From batch update seems impossible lock same tables in the same order because connection used in other places of application.

Comment: Sorry, but your description is too vague.

Answer (score 0):

1. EXCLUSIVE MODE is overkill, remove lock or change to ROW EXCLUSIVE.
2. Replace loop with batch update like:

```
    UPDATE a 
    FROM (VALUES
        ('id1', 1),
        ('id2', 2),
        ...
    ) AS val(id, status) 
    WHERE a.id = val.id;
```

to make it at least 100 time faster and decrease DB load.

### Conclusion

From logs seen - proc1 hung forever and block almost all access to table_a.
Changes 1. and 2. solved a problem.
It is still unclear what blocked proc1 after it acquired the lock, but figuring it out requires a lot of effort to reproduce this situation, which is not practical.